# Приложения на Golang под андроид

Tags: android, golang, mobile-development

Суть вопроса в том, как начать писать на Go приложения для андроид? именно пошаговое решение.
Искал много но ничего не понятно :D
Возможно просто я тупой или ещё мало опыта в этом, вам решать

Comment: куда интереснее был бы ответ на вопрос "как писать на go на самом устройстве"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так в официальном репозитории есть [документ с описанием](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile).

Или можно вот [этот](https://github.com/xlab/android-go) проект использовать, он попроще. [Простой](https://github.com/xlab/android-go/tree/master/examples/minimal) пример.

Что нужно:

- Установленный последний Android SDK.
- Задан `$ANDROID_HOME` в переменных среды.

А дальше дело техники.